# How to go about making a playlist that checks over and over again?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml

I'm working on an application that allows users to watch movies together regardless of timezones and in sync with each other. The problem though is this.

I think I'm going to have to use AJAX to check back with the databases or whatever my solution comes to.

JavaScript is used here...

On the load of the page the application does a bunch of math to make sure that they are watching the exact same duration of the movie even if they refresh the page. So everything works for at least 1 video. I set two variables. The time the movie starts and the minutes of the time that start. For example:

Say Winnie the Pooh starts at 10:30 am

```
var movieH = 10;
var movieM = 30;
```

And with a bunch of math that gets all calculated. Here's where the problem comes in.

I need something that stores all of these time externally whether it's PHP, MySQL, XML, or whatever. Like:

0:00 Tiger Movie
1:30 Live Free Die Hard
2:45 Tron Legacy
4:00 Gravity
6:00 Cinderella

(etc) All running on a 24 hour clock meaning up to 0:00-24:00

So, like this....

1. Page is Visited
2. JavaScript Starts
3. Loads the first starting time from the movie into those variables
4. Does the math
5. Movie plays
6. Movie ends
7. Goes to a new function and checks the times again and gets the starting time for the next
8. Plays document.getElementById('player').src changes to that movie path
9. Math is done again
10. Movie is played
11. Movie Ends
12. And, keeps doing the same process over and over again.

I can't really submit the code but what I have submitted is essential and really all that is needed.

Comment: This feels more like a request for someone to write - or at least design - your application for you, than a specific question which would fit this site. You might be better off finding someone you can pay to help, or starting an open source project to collaborate on it.

Comment: No I have everything completely written and it gets quite complex especially in design. It's just this one specific aspect. I can write all of the code as far as all of the JavaScript and AJAX goes but as far as storing the times for the playlist it's weird. I just have to have something for the two variables to check and import something from the database.

Comment: really a small and stupid aspect.

Comment: I'm going to manually put everything in. I mean even some guidance or idea on how this would be done in theory. Can I use XML Schema and asign elements to it and just add one to the first used element. Or See, I have no idea where to begin and I've been spending all week trying to think on how this one aspect could be fixed. Everything works I just need it to update or a general idea to movie through the database. Not an answer... if my work were done for me that'd be pretty crappy

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Are you asking what the database should look like? How to write code that accesses a database? How to build this into the application we've never seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's probably a little affronting to say can't submit code and then request us to design something for you and provide you with the code.

That said, its unclear exactly what you're asking for? Are you asking how to set up a Data driven website? Scope is too large for an SO question. Are you asking how to query a DB with Ajax? What set up do you have?

If you have a DB connected then its simple. Either you output the move duration to an invisible div in PHP:

```
$movies = [

["name" => 'Tiger Movie', "duration" => "1:30"],
["name" => 'Die Hard', "duration" => "1:50"]

] 

echo "<div id='durations' style='display: none;'>";
foreach($movies as $movie)
{
    print("<div class='movie'><span class='name'>". $movie['name'] . "</span><span class='duration'>" . $movie['duration'] . "</span></div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Then you can collect the values on page load with javascript ( example uses jQuery ):

```
var movies = $(".movie");
var moviesArray = new Array();

movies.each(function() {
        moviesArray.push({name: $(".name", this).text(), duration: $(".duration", this).text()});
});

console.log(moviesArray);
```

Or, if you want to use AJAX ( example uses jQuery ):

```
var data = "movies=TigerMovie";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getmovies.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
      },
      dataType: dataType
    });
```

In your PHP file `getmovies.php`:

```
if(isset($_POST['movies'])
{ 
      $movie = $_POST['movies'] //not escaped, as I'm trying to be quick, but always escape AJAX calls
      $mysqli = new mysqli(CONN,USER,PASS,DB);

      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT duration FROM movies WHERE name=?");
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $movie);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($duration);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();

      echo $duration;

}
```

Comment: Didn't fully fit my code, as anticipated, but you gave me an idea rather than just fixing my code. It's just when I have an original idea I prefer doing people throwing me ideas that help spawn a better more original idea than just saying, "How do I do this with the code I already wrote." Also I don't want other people stealing my hard earned work. I mean once it's finished, uploaded and stuff that's okay because I have the upload logs and everything in my system that will allow me to prove that I wrote it. You didn't fully answer my question and still left me with a general idea how to do it.